# How to deal with over 100 moving rectangles without lag

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/e6uwqnof/2/

On button press it creates 50 rectangles that all move down towards the bottom of the screen.

```
for(i=0;i<50;i++){
enemyArray.push(new enemy(normalBullet.x+i*5, normalBullet.y, normalBullet.speed, 1, 10, "#F00"));
}
```

Works fine on first click, but once I start adding more, it really starts to lag. Is there a best of practice way of dealing with hundreds of moving elements ? Or is HTML and Javascript not the best language to deal with this amount of moving data ?

Comment: @Gothdo Um, the fiddle *is* using a canvas.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol take it he said to use Canvas :L

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I didn't look at the fiddle, but I saw that OP is talking about DOM elements so I assumed they're not using Canvas.

Comment: @Gothdo my bad, I'll edit the question

Comment: @thisOneGuy I think that part of the problem may be that you assign event listener to `#newEnemy` every time `update()` is called.

Comment: Indeed, I don't see any lags after removing it outside `update` function. See [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gothdo/e6uwqnof/3/).

Comment: @Gothdo perfect. Solved my problem, thank you :)) Someone has also answered with the same solution :) appreciate it

Comment: For a another fps improvement, there is a software design principle which dictates you should separate what changes from what stays the same. You can apply this to your graphics. You have the same background every time. So, you can draw it once at the beginning as the background of the canvas, or a second canvas behind another. This leaves you only clearing and drawing bullets on the top canvas, this should help as well.

Comment: @TheCrzyMan I've been meaning to look how to do this as I thought to myself it is pointless redrawing stuff if it stays the same. How do I go about only clearing, say, the bullets and not the background which is consistent ?

Comment: @thisOneGuy There are a few ways that can be implemented for this. For easy dynamic updates, you put another canvas on the page. Set ´canvas.style.position="absolute";´ then set their positions to the same point, and their z-index such that the background canvas is lower than the foreground. Google will be your friend. Look up something like "javascript canvas background foreground", and that should point you in a good direction

Comment: @TheCrzyMan great stuff, ill get on to it. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your main problem is in the `update` function:

```
function update() {
  //  enemy.update();
  //if (keystate[SpaceBar]) {
  $('#newEnemy').click(function() {
    createNewEnemy()
  })
  //...
}
```

Probably a mistake, but you're attaching the event *every time `update` gets called*, which is 60 times per seconds! (Until it can't do it anymore, that is.)
This means that every time you press the button, you generate *a ton of elements* right in the canvas.

Move the event listener addition outsite `update` and you're golden.

Comment: Maybe the downvoter cares to explain? This *is* the answer, after all.

Comment: Perfect, here's the updated solution if anyone else is interested : https://jsfiddle.net/reko91/e6uwqnof/4/. Not sure why they downvoted, probably the same person down voted my question. I think it was a legitimate question on my part. Anyway appreciate it, thank you

Comment: @thisOneGuy Yes, that's a legit question indeed. Let me straighten that downvote up :)

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning button pushes inside the frame loop, so when you push it, it's actually calling the button push however many times the loop has run.

Move this code outside:

```
$('#newEnemy').click(function() {
  console.log("createEnemy");
  createNewEnemy()
});
```

Comment: offsetting your dv...  not a fan of political dvs.

Comment: @djechlin what do you mean by 'offsetting your dv' ?

Comment: you got a downvote, so I upvoted, not because I think it's a great answer, but because I think it was stupid to downvote it (I think someone just didn't like the question and tantrummed about it.)

Comment: @djechlin those people are the worst. Thank you :)